# JPA embeddable entity with composite id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a rather simple schema, I think, but I can't find the right way of mapping it.

```
@Entity
class Satellite {
   @Id
   private int id;
   // stuff
   @ElementCollection @OrderBy(value = "orbit asc")
   private List<DataModel> dataModel;
}
```

the embeddable class is the following:

```
class DataModel {
    private int orbit;
    private int data;
}
```

the problem is, orbit should be unique for each satellite. In my mind the table representing datamodel has a composite primary key composed of the satellite id and orbit. But I can't find the right way of mapping it. If I declare the DataModel as a plain entity, I have to add a satellite field mapped manytoone and a composite primary key that include satellite and orbit, but it does not works (stack overflow!!).

I'm using hibernate as persistence provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I declare the DataModel as a plain entity, I have to add a satellite field mapped manytoone and a composite primary key that include satellite and orbit.

On the db level you'd have to do that anyways, i.e. the table containing the `DataModel` would need a foreign key to the satellite. In that case I don't see a reason not to make `DataModel` an entity:

```
@IdClass( DMKeyClass.class )
@Entity
class DataModel {
  @Id
  private Satellite sat;
  @Id
  private int orbit;
  private int data;
}

class DMKeyClass {
  public int sat;
  public int orbit;
}
```

Comment: @fer.marino yes, I left that out for simplicity, but it shouldn't be a problem as long as you use the `mappedBy` attribute on the `Satellite` side (`DataModel` would be the owner of that relation).

Comment: well, adding the manytoone annotations create a stack overflow in hibernate. Apparently, he gets in a loop when he resolve this relation. After a brief search, I solved it using a lazy fetching on that relation. 
Thank you for your help Thomas!

Comment: another strange problem that is happening now is a memory leak on the datamodel class. Those classes are used inside an algorithm, and for some reason someone (not me, hibernate?) is creating a huge amount of instances of datamodel, and without passing from the no arg constructor. It is very strange! It do that even when I'm not using the datamodel!

The problem disappear if I break this relation, but of course I need it.

Comment: @fer.marino can you please post your mapping?